# How to clean the cache of Outlook add-ins?

Tags: outlook-web-addins

I'm testing a JavaScript add-in on Outlook for Windows version 16.0.12228.20100 32-bit.
[These recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=clean%20outlook%20add-in%20cache) do not work.
Is there any reliable way of cleaning add-in cache to test immediately after editing the JavaScript source code?

Update: Thanks for answer but clearing the cache of web browser does not clear the cache of Outlook. Do you know any undocumented way to reload the add-in in Outlook?

Comment: replaced outlook-addin tag with outlook-web-addins

Comment: You can either force clear the cache going into the settings of the browser and even select to load web pages everytime that they are visited instead of having the browser caching them.

Comment: To double check, what's your windows version?  For more recent versions, the add-in is running in Microsoft Edge, you can clear the cache in the Edge DevTools. More information here on attaching https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-using-f12-developer-tools-on-windows-10.  There's a clear cache and always refresh from server button under Networks tab.

Comment: I'm running Windows 10 pro 32 bit Version10.0.18362 Build 18362. Clearing the cache of edge doesn't clear the cache of Outlook.

Comment: To clarify, for add-ins you need to clear the cache of Edge WebView which is different from Edge Browser. To do this, please follow the instructions above.

Comment: Which "instructions above" do you mean? "Debug add-ins using developer tools on Windows 10" article has no any word "cache". What exactly should I do to clear the cache of Edge WebView?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to update the HTML/JS you should be able to put focus into the Add-in, then hit "Ctrl-F5"

If this doesn't work you can follow instructions below for more detailed instructions on how to clear other parts of the cache.

You first need to [install Edge DevTools and attach a debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-using-f12-developer-tools-on-windows-10) to your add-in.

1) launch Edge Dev Tools. (not F12 Chooser)

[image]

2) Open your Add-in in Outlook

3) Edge Dev Tools should show your add-in under Debug Targets. You may need to refresh Edge Dev Tools.

4) Once attached to your add-in, the debugger will have a clear cache button under the Network tab.

[image]

5) If this does not work, you can also try clicking on the "Always Refresh From Server" Then putting focus in the add-in and hitting ctrl-F5 to refresh the pane and load from server instead of cache.

[image]

6) You can also add "no-cache" headers to your HTML page, though it is not recommended to ship with those tags for performance reasons.

Comment: Well I can attach  to F12 tool an add-in that runs in Edge, but the same add-in running in Outlook is never detected.

Comment: The F12 debugger will work for web browsers (Chrome, Edge, Firefox etc..). To attach a debugger in Outlook Desktop which uses Edge WebView (different from Edge browser), you need to use Edge DevTools to detect the add-in.

Comment: After installing Edge DevTools I got an icon named "F12" (Attach Chooser Executable) that starts "C:\Windows\System32\F12\IEChooser.exe". Do you mean there exists another "Edge DevTools"?

Comment: While running the add-in in Edge, open that program you installed named "Microsoft Edge DevTools". There is a Local tab that should have the add-in listed by its name.

Comment: Are you kidding? I know how to debug an add-in with Edge. My question was how to clear the cache of Outlook. You told me that if fact I have to clear the cache of mysterious "Edge WebView (different from Edge browser)". How?

Comment: Apologies, I have updated the instructions. The tools to clear the cache / load from server are in the Edge Dev Tools program that must be attached before those options are available. I understand that this is not ideal, and this feedback has been forwarded to the appropriate parties, but at this time this is the only way to force an update.

Comment: Following up with the area owners. Actually just putting focus into the Add-in and doing "Ctrl-F5" should force a reload. If you want to clear other settings such as local storage/cookies/etc you may need to do the more complicated steps.

Comment: I'm afraid I do not catch you point. Could you please provide me a link to the detailed illustrated instructions how to clear the add-in cache in Outlook? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think there are detailed instructions? It's basically click the taskpane add-in so that mouse and keyboard focus is in the Add-in. Then on your keyboard hit Ctrl-F5. I've tried to update the answer here to be more detailed. What part is confusing?

Comment: Just to make sure: You are on a Taskpane Add-in?

Comment: No I'm trying to debug OnSend add-in in Outlook.

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't have a great solution for clearing the cache for OnSend add-ins in Outlook. One way is to add a simple Taskpane add-in (using the same domain / sourcelocation as the OnSend add-in) and then using Edge DevTools to clear the cache for the Taskpane. That will also clear the cache for the OnSend add-in. Alternatively, you could validate your add-in using the browser-based version of Outlook (instead of the native desktop client) so that you can easily clear the cache.