# Outlook add-in cache

Tags: caching, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I'm developing an Outlook add-in, which works fine in the OWA, but I've had trouble with the Outlook desktop client, specifically that it caches all files (js, css, as well as html). You'd think that restarting my Outlook client (or restarting the computer) would clear the cache, but no. The old version was kept. [These instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/clear-cache) also didn't do the trick.

Following the instructions of [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59031399/how-to-clean-the-cache-of-outlook-add-ins), I was finally able to clear the cache and see my new version in action.

However, I'm left with the question how the Outlook desktop client caches add-in files. Compounding the mystery is the fact that some of my colleagues experienced the same problem, while some did see the new version when I deployed it, even though they kept their Outlook client open continually.

So, what exactly is the mechanism by which the Outlook cache is refreshed? Is there some setting in the Outlook client that determines this? Surely, there must be a less cumbersome way to clear the Outlook add-in cache than using those Edge DevTools.

Comment: On which platform this issue is happening Mac or Windows?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The caching mechanism is determined by the underlying browser, not the Outlook Desktop client. The problem you are experiencing is alleviated by the new Microsoft Edge (Chromium-based) brower. [This documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins) has a matrix of the Outlook + Windows configurations that support the new Chromium-based Edge browser as the underlying browser for running Outlook/Office add-ins. For a taskpane add-in, you can simply refresh the add-in by right-clicking the pane, and selecting Refresh. For an On-Send or a Ui-Less add-in, you may still have to go through the workaround of creating a taskpane to help clear the cache.

Comment: Hmm, I don't seem to be able to right-click in the taskpane (I mean in the vertical area that pops up, just to be clear). I'm running Windows 1909 with Outlook Version 2012 (Build 13530.20376 Click-to-Run).

It seems that my caching problem is resolved, because of the Always Refresh toggle in the Edge DevTools. Though that's good news, I still wonder how we can solve this problem for end users, when we want to publish new features. I don't think it's feasible to guide each of them through the Edge DevTools. Is there another way?

Comment: For end users, they will all gradually get your changes as their individual caches expire. You can also disable browser caching for your add-in or control the cache expiration of files served by your webserver. I believe this meta tag can help disable browser caching of your html pages for example: `<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />`