# When updating an Outlook Add-In, how can I force Outlook to recognise the update i.e. stop the browser etc. from caching the old version?

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

We are finding that updating an Outlook App-In results in a long propagation time (more than hours, possibly a day or more); for development purposes this can be circumvented by a) using the web app, rather than Desktop b) using an in-private browser - but that is no use for production deployment ...

I'm updating using Filezilla (an FTP client), as it's fast

Re-starting Outlook, even re-booting the device, does not seem to help

Is there any work-around simple enough for end users who use Outlook Desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the [Cache-Control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) HTTP header fields that hold directives (instructions) — in both requests and responses — that control caching in browsers and shared caches (e.g. Proxies, CDNs). So, when the browser requests a file, you instruct the browser how frequently a file should be requested anew from the server.

If you have access to users machines you may [Clear the Office cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/clear-cache). To clear the Office cache on Windows 10 when the add-in is running in Microsoft Edge, you can use the Microsoft `Edge DevTools`.

Comment: So I can use cache-control directives in my html file (index.html)? But how do I avoid loosing all the benefits of caching? i.e. surely I don't really want to force JS file(s) to be fetched every time? Might "cache busting" suit this use case?

Comment: There is no mechanism for forcing updates - you need to decide on your own how frequently files will be requested.

Comment: On deployment, I see the Outlook Add-ins Team recommended using the meta tag: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65806172/outlook-add-in-cache; would you also recommend this method?

Comment: Yes, you can use the meta HTML tag on web pages as a possible solution.