# how do you clear the outlook addon | add ins cache via browser?

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am developing an outlook officejs add on. When we remove and re-add the add on, it often caches the old files and doesnt over write even though the manifest has an incriminating ver number or/and the GUID is changed.

I found this link to remove the cache on the local box if using the client, but what if you're using the browser? This doesnt seem to work.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/clear-cache

The same question was asked in 2020 with no solution (I have tested all these steps) [How to clean the cache of Outlook add-ins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59031399/how-to-clean-the-cache-of-outlook-add-ins)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

MS confirmed <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> refreshed the pane. We were also able to disable caching from developer. Reason for our issue was due to pulling the wrong repo and hence changes were not taking effect. Skool boy error.

Comment: @M Haynes how did you disable the cache in developer mode? I couldn't find anything in the docs

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to clear the cache from the web add-in. Instead, you may consider using mime headers for caching control of your files by the browser on the end user machines. Read more about that in the [HTTP caching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching) and [Cache-Control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) pages on MDN.

Comment: I've since spoken to MS. They have advised if you select the pane and hit CTRL+F5 it will hard refresh that pane. The reason this was not working for me, was because there was in fact an error in our code pulling the wrong repo. In addition, they showed us the disabled cache function in developer mode, which is now used A LOT.

Answer (score 0):

I find that ctrl- F5 does not always respond. Often if I insist by tapping the ctrl- F5 a number of times it works. The first indication that it is working is the taskpane goes blank and then is rewritten. The obvious check is to verify the running program reflects the change(s).

I believe that there is room improve the response of ctrl-F5. Perhaps it could be included in the Personality Menu of the taskpane such as the Reload. There again I would have thought that the reload would do a complete fresh reload of the Office Add-in including html, css, js, etc.