# outlook web addin manifest changes not reflecting even after changing the manifest version on localost

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I changed the Display Name and Description attributes in the manifest and published the addin (on localhost:3000). when I open the outlook addin on web, the changes are not reflecting.

I cleared the browser cache, deleted all the files under ..\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Wef
followed all the steps given in [how do you clear the outlook addon | add ins cache via browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71086263/how-do-you-clear-the-outlook-addon-add-ins-cache-via-browser)

still the new values/changes are not reflected. I can see old manifest file in below folder.

AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Wef{GUID}{GUID}\Manifests ...

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for that issue? i'm suffering the exact same sh... situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manifest update scenario works only for store addins. For side loaded addin, you need to remove the already installed addin and add it again.